# How to turn an [object Object] into an array?

Tags: arrays, object, angular, ngfor

I'm displaying some values from an API call into an ngFor directive. I'm trying to convert the data into an array. This is what i get from the server :

[Data from the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0uW6.png)

I subscribe the data like this :

```js
 onVideoClick(video_id) {
    this._dashboardService.getVideoData(video_id)
      .subscribe(videoData => {
        if (videoData.ok) {
          console.log(videoData.json());
          this.videoData = videoData.json();
        } else {
          console.log('pas de données vidéos');
        }
      });
  }
```

I display my data this way :

```html
     <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let vD of videoData">{{vD.attr_libelle}}</th>
     </tr>
```

How turn this Object into an array ?

Comment: Please add the JSON as text, not as screenshot.

Comment: You need to specify into what you want object to be transformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a custom pipe for this. Here is a sample one that creates an array from object entries:

```
@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]);
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
```

and use it like that:

```
<span *ngFor="#entry of content">           
  Key: {{entry.key}}, value: {{entry.value}}
</span>
```

Don't forget to add the pipe into the `pipes` attribute of the component where you want to use it.

Comment: How can i custom this pipe to resolve a complex object like an object into an object into an object ?

Comment: Which structure do you expect for your output object?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the library Lodash for this conversion.

```js
onVideoClick(video_id) {
    this._dashboardService.getVideoData(video_id)
      .subscribe(videoData => {
        if (videoData.ok) {
          console.log(videoData.json());
          this.videoData = _.values(videoData.json());
        } else {
          console.log('pas de données vidéos');
        }
      });
  }
```

For documentation see [here](https://lodash.com/docs#values).